# How to move wamp server 2.2 to another drive?

Tags: wampserver, wamp

I have drive `D:` where my wamp server 2.2 was on for years and needed to move it to SSD drive `F:`. I proceeded like this:

1. stopped all wamp services, exited aestryan menu
2. copied wamp installation without **www** (too much junk)  folder, from drive `D:` to drive `F:`
3. created fresh www folder copied one WP install in there including original wamp `index.php` and `loader-wizard.php`
4. used PowerGrep to replace all instances of `D:/wamp` to  `F:/wamp`
5. checked all ini/config files ,php,  phpMyadmin, aliases, apache, the new drive letter is set.
6. Double clicked `wampmanager.exe`  located in `F:/wamp` (new drive)
7. Server started, aestryan menu up,  www Directory clicked it pulls correct folder `F:\wamp\www`
8. went in my browser to localhost

It shows installations from  drive `D:` (old drive)! What am I missing?

**Solution:**  You MUST reinstallit the wamp, I was hoping on simple move but looks like wamp services map the localhost to the drive you originally installed the wamp on.

Comment: Did you delete the cache in your browser(s)? Simple, but often overlooked.

Comment: sure , did ,  dev tools  cache  disable on, checked in other browsers , check over remote locations.  same .  wamp services seems like hard mapping the localhost to drive letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For wamp 2.5 on Windows, use a text editor, e.g. notepad++ to edit `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf`

Change `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"` to `DocumentRoot "c:/my/new/path"` (Note slash direction). This will change the location where files are served from (~Line 230).

Change `<Directory "c:/wamp/www">` to `<Directory "c:/my/new/path">` (Note slash direction). This applies permissions from the old directory to the new one (~Line 252).

**Update:** Is the F drive a data drive, a system drive or a partition? If it is not a system drive it is pretty much impossible to install the server there, since there is no "exe" support milieu on a non-system, or data, drive. If it is a system drive/partition, then you may indeed need to install it on F drive and just move over your files.

Comment: It sounds like the powergrep step (#4) should have caught that.  Unless the grep wasn't done in the correct directory or was done case sensitive such that `C:` wouldn't have matched `c:`.

Comment: Good eye or thought. I was thinking it's an incorrect path in general opposed to the drive being case sensitive and not being resolved with powergrep..

Comment: @norcaljohnny,  everything is changed correctly ,  150% sure,  the issue seems in wamp services , looks like the install maps the localhost to the designated drive on install and you cant change it without uninstalling/reinstalling the wamp

Comment: @Benn please see update.

Comment: @norcaljohnny, it is a system drive , 2 drives , D is raptor, F is Agility SSD

Comment: Then you may indeed need to install it on F drive and just move over your files.

Comment: @norcaljohnny I was hoping not to but yes seems like I have to